# How do I run Debian via VirtualBox using the physical partitions (rawdisk)?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

**Disclaimer:** My question is different to and not answered in any of these *similar* questions:

1. [VirtualBox: using physical partition as virtual drive](https://superuser.com/questions/392601/virtualbox-using-physical-partition-as-virtual-drive)
2. [Running Mac OS X Physical Partition Inside VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/216370/running-mac-os-x-physical-partition-inside-virtualbox)
3. [Use VirtualBox to boot a physical drive/partition](https://superuser.com/questions/451573/use-virtualbox-to-boot-a-physical-drive-partition)

**Info:** I have a Debian 8 (stable, jessie) OS installed collectively on four partitions on my HDD.

1. `/boot`
2. `/`
3. `/home`
4. `swap`

My main OS, on the same hard disk drive is Windows 8.1. I’d like to, using [`rawdisk`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idp97352672), gain access to my Debian OS, through VirtualBox

**Tried:** I have tried using this command:

> VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\Users\relax\VMs\Debian 8\data.vmdk" -rawdisk \.\PhysicalDrive0 -partitions 3,4,5,6

But it fails, saying:

> VirtualBox Command Line Tool has stopped working

[image: error]

However, when I remove the partitions parameter, it creates the file and says it’s successful.

[image: success]

Drive info:

It's the only drive:
[image: drive]

Partition List:
[image: partition list]

Partitions I want: (Zero-based index)
[image: Partitions I want]

**Question:** How do I successfully run my Debian OS from a physical partition via VirtualBox?

Comment: Not that familiar with the way  Windows + vbox  shows formatted partitions  but are 3-6 formatted and in a linux friendly format ?  if not that COULD explain the failure  ---does the successful  run without partitions param  leave partitions in place?

Comment: Partitions 3-6 are formatted in ext4. Yes, the partitions do stay in place.

Comment: Odd should stay that way with params too

Answer (score 0):

I also make some similar.

Look at your block sizes and to your picture.
The something incorrect:

```
Partition No/Block Size/Partition Size:
0 / 204800 / 100 MB
1 / 167772160 / 80 GB
2 / 149407744 / 71 GB
3 / 29296640 / 13 GB
4 / 25169920 / 12 GB
5 / 68360192 / 32 GB
6 / 59432960 / 28 GB
7 / 206548 / 100 MB
```